# I need help making a submodule file for github

Tags: github

I am trying to get my assignment submitted through GitHub, but I keep getting the no submodules error and I can't view it.

So I added one, but it seems it's incorrect, I'm guessing because of the space between Assignment 3, it made it harder to understand, but I can't figure it out.

So I don't know if my path is correct or even if my URL is correct.
I don't understand how to fix this.

My GitHub directory:

[image: GH dir]

My submodules file:

[image: .gitmodules]

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Are you trying to add your github repo "Assigment 3" as a submodule?

Answer (score 0):

The "no submodule" error should not be related to your '`Assignment 3`' subfolder.

Since it is a subfolder, it cannot be added as a submodule: said submodule references a repository, not a folder inside a repository.

So you need to specify the exact command and error message in order for us to diagnostic the actual cause.